# Dynamic url laravel

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have an app that search for places in citys.

I have this route

```
  Route::get('s/{where}/{places}', 'SearchController@places')->name('search');
```

The SearchController

```
class SearchController extends Controller{

public function places(Request $request, $where, $places)
{   
    $where = $request->where;
 
    if($places == 'places'){
        return view('search.places', ['where' => $where]);
    }else{
         abort('404');
    }
 }
}
```

I also have tried with

```
   ->with()
```

The form submission to search

```
 <form action="{{ route('search' ,  ['where', 'places']) }}" method="get">
```

I am getting something like this:

http://localhost/s/where/places?where=Paris

What i want is

http://localhost/s/paris/places

when it shoul replace the where in the url and not add where after the question mark!

Thanks for help

Comment: Your method is wrong, try this `{{ route('search' ,  ['where' => 'France', 'places' => 'Paris']) }}`

Comment: Thanks for you coment but the link should be dynamic when i submit the form i don't no if is is france or paris or china! thats why i send where but in controller i want to change the where to the city the user as submit

Comment: The field is dynamic `{{ route('search' , ['where' => $countey, 'places' => $city]) }}` hope you understand now

Comment: In the form i don't have $countey or $city defined?? The problem is in the controller not the form! Thanks for you help

Comment: `where` and `places` are the optional parameter?

Comment: Main page as a form with autocomplete from google, ok than the users types the city Paris, now i am submiting this to my controller when i return the view with the results page i also whant to put in the url the city name

Answer (score 0):

Based on how you set your route you need to set as below:

```
<form action="{{ route('search' ,  ['where' => 'paris', 'places' => 'places']) }}" method="get">
```

Comment: OMG, please read what i want as final result! i don't want any predefined where OK it can have or no! I don't have any var defined in blade to set the where! i have a main page with a form with autocomplete i put the city i want i submit the form in the controller when i return the view with the results i want also set the contry or city name in the url

Comment: Based on how you created your route, you need to set route() helper method as above, if not, that means that you set wrong your route parameters.
Kindly review https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes

Comment: And please how i should make a route that have a optional paramter? and can make something like this: 
form submited with city
when return view return the data, and change the url, or add info to the url like this
http://localhost/s/paris/places 
or i have to create two routes and is impossible to do with just 1 route

Comment: You set a route as `s/{where}/{places}` , this means that when you call this route you need to pass 2 parameters (one for where and one for places)
If you only need to pass `where`, then you need to set your route as `s/{where}/places`, and then you pass only one parameter in your route helper method `route('search', 'paris'` or `route('search', ['paris'])` or `route('search', ['where' => 'paris'])`.

Comment: In your controller you do not NEED to do $request->where, because you got $where variable as parameter in your method places -->  `public function places(Request $request, $where, $places)`, $where will contain `paris` in the previous example.

Comment: i think i am not explaing very well, just to finish do you know if it is possible to change or update the url for exemple i send http://localhost/s/where/places and in the controller before a return the view change the where parameter in the url?

Comment: You cannot change or update in the controller, what you can do in the controller is `return redirect()->route('new_route');`.